# Why are my Boolean variables not changing their values inside a route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm simply doing a get route for my back-end, and I can't figure out why my variables user and pass are still false when I console.log them. Is there any other way/function rather than findOne to check if both username and password are correct?

```
app.get('/connect', (req, res) => {
    let user = false;
    let pass = false;
    User.findOne({login: req.query.login}).then((currentUser) => {
        if (currentUser)
            user = true;
    })
    User.findOne({password: req.query.password}).then((currentPassword) => {
        if (currentPassword)
            pass = true;
    })
    console.log(user); //prints still false
    console.log(pass); //prints still false
});
```

Comment: If it is async, you need to await them or nest them.  If you dont await, it will call the calls and keep going, immediately dumping false, but changing the values after the requests finish.  If you let me know if that solves your issue, I can write something up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the await is the resolution.

As mentioned above, due to async nature, it will fire those requests and immediately keep going.  This is why your console will print false, but at N time later, they are in fact changed.

You can set a function as Async by saying:

```
async (a,b) => {}
```

if you are using shorthand. and afterwards, you can just say: `await functioncall();` for ant async calls you need to handle.

***Just remember, that if you want to await something, the parent function needs to be async.  Thats the real take away here.***

To put it all together, given your code is as follows:

```
app.get('/connect', async (req, res) => { // If you leverage await, you need to define parent function as async by a keyword.
    let user = false;
    let pass = false;
    //you tell this function to wait until it has fully finished its promise chain.
    await User.findOne({login: req.query.login}).then((currentUser) => {
        if (currentUser)
            user = true;
    })
    // Same as above
    await User.findOne({password: req.query.password}).then((currentPassword) => {
        if (currentPassword)
            pass = true;
    })
    console.log(user); //now will print true.
    console.log(pass); //now will print true.
});
```

I noted key changes above.

Comment: Perfect explanation

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your DB searchs asynchronous. You can make use of async/await to accomplish that.

```
app.get('/connect', async (req, res) => {
let user = false;
let pass = false;

const currentUser = await User.findOne({login: req.query.login});
if (currentUser)
    user = true;

const currentPassword = await User.findOne({password: req.query.password});
if (currentPassword)
    pass = true;

console.log(user);
console.log(pass);
});
```